# angularjs $http - why not get json?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I use the ionic framework   why not get json?

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'dwz.cn/create.php?url=www.qq.com'}).success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.= myUrl; // response data 
    });
})
```

view：

```
<ion-view title="url">
  <ion-content class="has-header padding">
           {{myurl}}
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

but This can be

```
.controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
    $http({method: 'GET', url: 'new.json'}).success(function(data)
    {
        $scope.= myUrl; // response data 
    });
})
```

Comment: `$scope.= myUrl;` <--- what's this?

Comment: shouldn't your `url`:` be `http://dwz.cn/create.php`? Without the http protocol bit, you're going to be looking for a `dwn.cz` subdirectory on your own server.

Comment: you're going to be looking for a dwn.cz subdirectory on your own server.  But I use the API

Comment: @user3652260: your browser has no idea you do. It will treat it as a path.

Comment: http://dwz.cn/create.php?url=www.qq.com  return json, But can not access

Comment: If you type the URL into your browser, your browser is smart enough to tack on HTTP at the beginning. When you do it in code, it will not do that. It takes it AS IS.